# How to subscribe to click event on Cluster Marker - agm-marker-cluster

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript

I am developing Angular 4 bases application where in I need to integrate google maps and have a functionality of displaying clusters. If there are multiple locations at same lat-long, a cluster is shown with the number of locations.Further, I need to display a popup dialog on clicking this cluster. I am able to get the clustering working using  agm-marker-cluster, but I am not sure the event to subscribe to, when the user clicks on the cluster. Can someone let me know how to go about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck with implementation of cluster click event?